# Are [s] and [z] allophones of the same phoneme in Spanish? What is the rule that predicts the distribution?

Tags: spanish, allophones

What is the rule that predicts the distribution?

Comment: If it's for a class, it would be helpful to know the theoretical framework you're using for allophonic rules. If you just want a description of the distribution, however, then it's [z] before phonetically voiced consonants and [s] in other places. Besides this pattern, though, many Spanish dialects use allophone [h] for a coda /s/. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Obstruents

Comment: thank you :) It is a homework question. We are given some data in Spanish and asked whether {s} and [z] are allophones of the same phoneme or separate phonemes. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?  Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unlike English , in Spanish [z] is only a realization of /s/ (where s becomes before voiced consonants), and appears nowhere else in the language. So it’s only an allaphone of the phoneme /s/ ; whereas in English, existance of minimmal pairs such as “sip” amd “zip” proves /z/ to be a distinct phoneme from /s/.

Answer (score 0):

Phonemically, there is no difference between [s] and [z]. In all Spanish dialects the phoneme /s/ is only slightly voiced [s̬] (sometimes written [z]), before voiced obstruents:

*esnob* /esnoB/ [es̬'nob] 'snob'

*esbelto* /es'Belto/ [es̬'β̞elto] 'slender, slim'.

on the other hand, elsewhere we have a voiceless [s]:

*España* /españa/ [es'paɲa] 'Spain'

*esfuerzo* /esfuerZo/ [es'fweɾθo]/[es'fweɾso] 'effort'

*esencial* /esenZial/ [esen'θjal]/[esen'sjal] 'essential'